# Should we rename [question2answer] to [php-question2answer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I just came across the tag [question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer) in a c# question. The tag clearly reads:

> A popular open source Q&A platform using PHP and MySQL. **(Please do not use this tag to indicate that you have a question and want an answer)**.

Emphasis mine.

That verbiage is obviously not read by users, as we all well know, and by looking at the top few questions with the tag we can confirm this:

- "how do i get a letter of a string variable using another variable; word[letter]" -> no other useful tag
- "Im new to coding" -> again, no useful tag, and useless title
- "I dont know how to make a stopwatch loop go to a web server and run the
  code with nodejs" -> nodejs, unrelated to PHP
- "How to fit `f(x)=a*sin^2(b*x^2 + c)` in Gnuplot [closed]" -> unrelated to PHP
- "Flash 8 `key.isDown` codes" -> unrelated to PHP

And I could go on and on. We may be able to ignore those questions tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer)

My suggestion here is to cleanup [question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer), close off-topic questions, and then rename the tag, perhaps to something like [php-question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-question2answer) (but some PHP users might have a better suggestion).

Comment: Looks like [tag:question-answering] could use a similar treatment.  There's one question that only has those 2 tags.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Agreed, but didn't want to make this question too broad

Comment: To be fair, I literally just added that part to the Wiki like a week ago or so. The majority of the questions had already been asked by that point. I agree with the name change though. Changing the description was all I could think of at the time.

Comment: IMO, the tag does not need renaming — it wouldn't be actively harmful to rename it, but it is unnecessary.  The (apparently quite recent) Wiki information points to the intended use.  Those questions with the tag that are not related to the PHP system should have the [tag:question2answer] tag removed — that's all.  There are only 69 questions using the tag.  At least one of them has only that tag but is a Python question.  That amount of work is manageable by a few (one or two) people with the powers (reputation) to do it in a short period of time, even with question cleanup.

Comment: There are somewhat fewer than 69 questions with the tag now.  The number will probably decrease over time.  Whatever the final decision on the tag name, retagging (untagging) the questions where the tag is manifestly irrelevant is A Good Thing™.  As @psubsee2003 noted, a surprising number of the questions are also tagged [tag:question-answering] and that tag too is manifestly irrelevant.

Comment: Please note — it is not helpful to edit these questions if your edit has to go through the review queue.  That makes more work for more people.    If you don't already have 2000 in reputation, please leave the changes to those with more than 2000 reputation.

Comment: The tag is now at 48 questions, all of which should have the tag on them.

Comment: Well there are more of such tags. Often people tag a question [logic-programming], but it has nothing to do with Datalog, Prolog, Mercury, etc. But just with "programming some logic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring my comments to an answer.*</sup>

IMO, the tag does not need renaming.  It wouldn't be actively harmful to rename it, but it is unnecessary. The ([apparently quite recent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402541/should-we-rename-question2answer-to-php-question2answer?noredirect=1#comment805974_402541)) Wiki information points to the intended use.

Those questions with the tag that are not related to the PHP system should have the [question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer) tag removed — that's all. There were only 69 questions using the tag when I first looked at the list. At least one of those had only that tag but was a Python question — it is no longer tagged with [question2answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer) and *is* tagged with the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. That amount of work (editing fewer than 70 questions) is manageable by a few (one or two) people with the powers (reputation) to do it in a short period of time, even with question cleanup.  (If you do not have at least 2,000 reputation, please **do not** do the editing — it just makes unnecessary work for other people.  Thank you for trying.)

*[…time passeth…]* There are now somewhat fewer than 69 questions with the tag now. The number will probably decrease over time. Whatever the final decision on the tag name, retagging (untagging) the questions where the tag is manifestly irrelevant is A Good Thing™. As [psubsee2003](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250725/psubsee2003) noted, a surprising number of the questions are also tagged with the [question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-answering) tag and that too is manifestly irrelevant and should also be removed.  It's reasonable to guess that gullible askers started to type `question` into the tag box and got those two options offered, and chose one or both of them.

Comment: It's done. Down to 48 questions.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick — and those others who helped.  I agree that the questions left seem to be correctly tagged.

Comment: I didn't comment on [tag:question-answering] given that there are perfectly valid uses of the tag for NLP/bots. And agreed with this, just didn't want to make anything before getting some input from the community :)